# Getting Received Memory Warning while taking photo from camera in ios7 + phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, sencha-touch

I developed one application in phonegap and sencha touch. The application working fine in ios6  (i am not getting any memory warnings) but in ios7 i am getting received memory warnings regularly while taking photo from camera.After getting the memory warning the app crashed.
I am trying like this

```
takePhotoAction:function(){
     var destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
     navigator.camera.getPicture(this.takePhotoSuccess, this.takePhotoFail, {quality: 50,targetWidth:300,targetHeight:300,destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,sourceType:1,correctOrientation: true });
},
takePhotoSuccess:function(imgdata){
    console.log("Here we are giving the image data to the image src");
},
takePhotoFail:function(error){
    console.log("the error is "+error);
}
```

Please help me how can i resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Objective-C code?

Comment: no this is sencha touch and phonegap code

Comment: What's the version of phonegap? maybe ios7 not supported if you work with an older version

Comment: i am using cordova 2.4.0 version